# Replace multiple characters using MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, replace

i am using this piece of code to replace characters in one column of my database.

```
UPDATE items 
SET items = REPLACE(items, '&#x1E07;','ḇ')
```

But now I have a list with almost 500 characters to replace. 
Just writing the whole sequence of lines in one single query will not work.

```
UPDATE items 
SET items = REPLACE(items, '&#x1E07;','ḇ')
SET items = REPLACE(items, '&#x1E0x;','x')
SET items = REPLACE(items, '&#x1E0y;','y')
ETC.
```

Or I do not know how to write it. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You’ll have to put them inside each other. `REPLACE(REPLACE(items, ‘asd’, ‘def’), ‘qwe’, ‘rty’)` but with that many I would recommend using some other way of decoding the entities

Comment: Will MySQL be able to handle 500 nested REPLACE functions? If yes then I can generate the whole query using VBS or even Bach so problem solved.

Comment: It might, but sounds possible that it will not. I would write a script with any language that can decode those entities and would use that to do the job. If you want to decode all entities that would be a lot easier. Probably will be only a few of lines of Python for example

Comment: Is there a pattern to what they should be replaced with?

Comment: There is no specific pattern. I used codetable.net to asociate hex code with its coresponding symbol. I have already generated the query. I will check soon if MySQL will handle it. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table that has the search string and the replace string as columns. Add all 500 rows of what needs to be replaced. Then write a stored procedure that will lookup the replace value from the lookup table and replace with the value. The lookup table can easily be loaded into MySql from an Excel or csv file.

Here's the pseudo code to show the looping and lookup. I know it won't compile, I'm a bit rusty on MySql syntax. I usually work in Oracle so the pseudocode syntax is more Oracle-esque.

```
DECLARE
v_old_string varchar;
v_new_string varchar;
BEGIN
FOR v IN (SELECT * FROM items) LOOP
   SELECT old_string, new_string
     INTO v_old_string, v_new_string
     FROM my_lookup_table
    WHERE old_string = v.thestringcolumn;

   UPDATE items
      SET itemcolumn = REPLACE(itemcolumn, v_old_string, v_new_string)
    WHERE itemcolumn = v_old_string;
END LOOP;
END;
```